# Menu page not showing in WP Admin section

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress eCommerce website in this website all working but admin menu page not working and the page showing blank, and I was trying to add a new image that image does not upload and not showing the old image in media library only loading process see attachment

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue, you need to see what error is causing this blank page. By default, PHP suppresses errors display for security reasons, but Wordpress has a setting to show the errors.

In order to turn on error display, open your wp-config.php in the root folder

And add these two lines:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

NOTE: You must insert this BEFORE /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ in the wp-config.php file.

You can read more here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Only after you do that you will be able to see the error instead of a blank page, and then share it here to help us solve it or google for solution yourself.